# Performance/Load/Stress Testing Orchestration layer

Tags: java, spring, performance-testing

We have a spring based application which acts as an orchestration layer which consumes other Rest Apis. 
I want to performance test only this component and not the downstream apis being consumed.

I am looking for any architectural suggestions as to how this can be done?

The current approach (flawed) is,
I have created end points specifically for these tests which functionally put the main thread to sleep for a fixed time (short, medium and long delays) and return mock responses eventually. The reason i put the main thread to sleep is to mimic the I/O operation when making an external rest api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the downstream API's on a different virtual host for their maximum out of spec condition, i.e. a sleep of 2500 milliseconds.   Run your test, subtract 2500 ms  plus your network delay from every timed event.

Comment: virtual host as in using service virtualization?

Comment: Virtual host has many contexts here, but in general this mock is service virtualization.  You can create a virtual host on your same web server software, where the virtualized service on your secondary virtual host.  It could be a virtual machine dedicated to your mocked service, but you will need to be careful of clock float inside of a software virtual machine for consistency in response